# React When receiving data from the server, the type is known, but only response.data does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When receiving data from the server, the type is known, but only response.data does not work.

If I just take a response, it works fine, but when I take a response.data it doesn't work.

ErrorMessage : Object is of type 'unknown.'

```js
import { UserState } from '../../lib/atom';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRecoilState } from 'recoil';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Resizer from 'react-image-file-resizer';
import CustomButton from '../../components/CustomButton';
import axios, { AxiosRequestHeaders, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { getCookie } from '../../lib/cookie/cookie';
import { checkUsernameApi } from '../../apis/apiClient';
import useDebounce from '../../hooks/useDebounce';

const headers: AxiosRequestHeaders = {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${getCookie('accessToken')}`,
};

function UserProfile() {
  const [userState, setUserState] = useRecoilState(UserState);
  const [imgText, setImgText] = useState('');
  const [username, setUserName] = useState(userState.username);
  const debounceUsername = useDebounce(username, 500);
  const [exist, setExist] = useState(false);
  function handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const revise_form = {
      email: userState.email,
      groupInfo: '39th',
      profileImg: userState.profileImg,
      username,
    };
    console.log('Revise_Form', revise_form);
    const response = axios.put(
      `http://localhost:8080/api/userprofile/${userState.username}`,
      revise_form,
      { headers }
    );
    console.log('put response', response);
  }

  async function FetchingUserName() {
    try {
      const response = await checkUsernameApi(username);
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      return err;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await FetchingUserName();
      console.log(response);
      /* eslint-disable-next-line */
      setExist(response.data);
    })();
  }, [debounceUsername]);

  function fileChangedHandler(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    if (e.currentTarget.files !== null) {
      const file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
      setImgText(file.name);
      Resizer.imageFileResizer(
        file,
        300,
        300,
        'JPEG',
        100,
        0,
        (uri) => {
          setUserState({ ...userState, profileImg: uri });
        },
        'base64',
        200,
        200
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <ProfileContainer>
      <RevisionForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Title>UserProfile</Title>
        <AvatarBox>
          <Avatar src={userState.profileImg + ''} alt="avatar" />
        </AvatarBox>
        <FileBox>
          <input
            type={''}
            placeholder="아바타를 업로드 해주세요."
            disabled={true}
            value={imgText}
          />
          <label htmlFor="user_avatar">Upload</label>
          <FileInput
            id="user_avatar"
            type="file"
            onChange={fileChangedHandler}
          />
        </FileBox>
        <InputBox>
          <label>email</label>
          <InputEmail type={'text'} value={userState.email} disabled={true} />
        </InputBox>
        <InputBox>
          <label>username</label>
          <Input
            type={'text'}
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setUserName(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </InputBox>
        <CustomButton
          height="4rem"
          bgColor="#5de0e6"
          color="white"
          width="18rem"
          weight="bold"
        >
          Revision
        </CustomButton>
        <ErrorText>{}</ErrorText>
      </RevisionForm>
    </ProfileContainer>
  );
}

export default UserProfile;
```

I want to get response from server and save only response.data in setExist.
The response.data received from the server is a boolean type.

However, this does not work even if the type is specified in useState() .

Is there anything else I need to specify in this code?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn0oq.png)

I have tried the methods below.

1. useState<boolean>(false)
   I put the Response type included in Axios.
2. useState<AxiosResponse>()

But the above methods didn't work.

Comment: Declaring the type in `useState` is not enough. You need to actually declare (or assert) it in the `axios.put` call. If you expect that `response` has the type `{data: boolean}`, you need to tell TypeScript - it won't guess!

Comment: Thanks I got the idea and solved the problem well!